# Programming an intelligent game-playing bot

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, minimax, behavior-tree

I am taking part in a programming competition where the objective is writing a bot that can play a specific game.
The objective of the game is to earn a certain amount of points. You control multiple airships, that you move around, capture islands and navigate drones that carry treasure. You play against one opponent, turns happen simultaneously, and there is a time limit. You can move multiple ships and drones in one turn. You can program your bot in Python, Java or C#.
The exact details don‘t matter, just that each ship has around 15 options each turn (moving and shooting) and overall you have around 10000 different options for each turn (different configurations of airship movements and shooting)
Up until now I approached this competition naively, and haven‘t done anything exceptionally clever (for example, if near enemy, shoot). I have read about minimax algorithms, and I would really like to apply it here (or something similar), you can assume that I can tell the value of a state. My problem is the mass of options for each turn - which create an enourmous branching factor that doesnt let me get very deep.

Question 1: Is there a better, applicable approach to this problem? Perhaps deep-learning or something similar?
Question 2: Is there a way to minimize the branching factor? I`ve read about alpha-beta and similar algorithms, but nothing seems to do the job.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: (1) ```you can assume that I can tell the value of a state``` - this i highly doubt (2) ```Is there a better, applicable approach to this problem?``` Better than what? You did only introduce one static rule. So of course (3) ```...Deep Learning``` This will take you months/years (4) ```Is there a way to minimize the branching factor?``` - Sure, move ordering and good eval-functions allow efficient pruning in alpha-beta. (5) [MCTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search) would be my natural first approach (6) This is a very tough and complex problem. Maybe try smth easier first.

Answer (score 0):

The minimax algorithm seems to be natural for these kinds of problems. At first, the game will be modelled in a abstract way and then a solver is used to find the path from current situation to a gamestate which maximize the amount of points. A similar approach to minimax is GOAP, which was implemented in the 1970'er for Shakey the robot under the name STRIPS. But, GOAP and minimax has two problems: first, a abstract model of the game is needed (perhaps in PDDL or in Game Description Language) and second the state-space is to big.

An better alternative to planning is to use a Behavior Tree. Thats a static program which describes the behavior of an agent. No solver is needed and no complete modelling of the game is needed. Instead, a bottom up approach is used with multiple edit-compile-run iterations for finding the optimal behavior tree (Test-driven-development). To implement such programming approach a so called "reactive planner" has to be implemented first which is another word for a realtime scheduler. Thats a module whichs maps a behavior tree onto a gantt-chart for executing an action at a specific moment in time. As introduction, the unity3d Engine is a good starting point, which has a full behaviortree implementation out-of-the-box.